# Serialize Java Object attribute to JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have an API built in Java Spring that return (using JacksonJaxbJsonProvider 2.5.5) a JSON object from this class:

```java
public class FieldValues {
    private String code;
    private Object value;
    
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

In the main object I've

```java
@JsonRootName(value = "WorkRequest")
@XmlRootElement(name = "WorkRequest")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class WorkRequestDTOResponse {   
    private List<FieldValues> fieldValues;
    public List<FieldValues> getFieldValues() {
        return fieldValues;
    }
    public void setFieldValues(List<FieldValues> fieldValues) {
        this.fieldValues = fieldValues;
    }
}
```

But the output of the ***fieldValues*** object is this:

```json
"fieldValues": [
    {
        "code": "anomaly",
        "value": {
            "@xsi.type": "ns3:boolean",
            "$": "true"
        }
    },{
        "code": "internal_note",
        "value": {
            "@xsi.type": "ns3:string",
            "$": "Test text example"
        }
    }
]
```

instead what I need is this:

```json
"fieldValues": [
    {
        "code": "anomaly",
        "value": true
    },{
        "code": "internal_note",
        "value": "Test text example"
    }
]
```

This is my JSON Provider:

```java
public class ErmesJSONProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {
    public ErmesJSONProvider() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
        
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED, false);

        _mapperConfig.setMapper(mapper);
        _mapperConfig.getConfiguredMapper().setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector());
    }
}
```

Trying to use a String instead an object:

```java
public class FieldValues {
    private String code;
    private String value;
```

But if I set this value as String `fieldValues.setValue("true")`, the JSON output is `"value": true` instead    `"value": "true"`

Likewise if I set this value as String but with an Integer `fieldValues.setValue("1")`, the JSON output is `"value": 1` instead `"value": "1"`

If I print the return object using ObjectMapper I've the right JSON:

```java
String payload = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(requestResult)
```

but if I return a Response like this:

```java
return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(new GenericEntity<RequestResult>(requestResult){}).build()
```

it return the wrong JSON.

I can't understand why

Someone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: show the code how are you setting the values using `setValue()`

Comment: @Deadpool I set value simply doing `fieldValuesBool.setValue(true)` and `fieldValuesText.setValue("Test text example")`